# ASP: Html Form action calls automatically on textbox OnTextChanged

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I have defined `form action` in my asp page and with in form, I have defined the `Textbox OnTextChanged`. but when I type any thing on `Textbox` and click on tap to move next.. automatically instead of calling `OnTextChanged` ..my form action calls..

my code is below

```
  <form id="WebToLead" action="https://url"   method="POST" runat="server">

<asp:TextBox id="a" name="a"  maxlength="10" runat="server"  OnTextChanged="a_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
// some more textbox
<asp:Button ID="Button2" Text="Click" width="50px"  runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click"  />
</form>
```

Means it action should be triggered on `button2_click` but it does when i type anything on `a`and tap to other fields

Comment: Remove `AutoPostBack="true"` and it will not auto post back any more.

Comment: but if remove it .. OnTextChanged is not getting called for textbox

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have viewstate enabled for this to work, otherwise Asp.Net has no way of knowing whether the control's value has changed.

Comment: Ontextchanged on called when i use AutoPostBack="true"

Answer (score 0):

AutoPostBack is enabled thats why it is posting the form back to server. Remove it or disable it. It should work after that.

Comment: but if remove it .. OnTextChanged is not getting called for textbox

Comment: USe Jquery to call that textChanged Event. Its very simple to do.

Comment: Right.. But I have to run the sql query in textChanged Event which i ws doing in C#, how do i run with Jquery

Comment: Two things: 1. Decorate your method with [WebMethod] attribute.        2. Make an AJAX call to invoke that method.